# How to create a java string in JNI C++?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

How can I create a String from C++ and send to a method in java?

Suppose I have an env and I need to simply create a jstring to send to a method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
env->NewStringUTF("Hello world")
```

So you can use like this:

```
jobject result = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(myClass, myMethod, env->NewStringUTF("Hello world"));
```